# Greenfoot java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, greenfoot-engine

When an enemy comes into contact with the hero the hero class is supposed to remove the enemy class with the same X and Y. It works the first time but throws an error immediately after that:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 
>  
>           at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653) 
>           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429) 
>           at Hero.checkCollision(Hero.java:39) 
>           at Hero.act(Hero.java:23)

```
public void act()
{
    ...
    checkCollision();
    ...
}
private void checkCollision() 
{
    Actor 2 = (Actor)getWorld().getObjects(2.class).get(0);
    if(2.getX() == getX() & 2.getY() == getY()) {
        getWorld().removeObject(2);
    }
    Actor 1 = (Actor)getWorld().getObjects(1.class).get(0);
    if(1.getX() == getX() & 1.getY() == getY()) {
        getWorld().removeObject(1);
    }
    Actor 3 = (Actor)getWorld().getObjects(3.class).get(0);
    if(3.getX() == getX() & 3.getY() == getY()) {
        getWorld().removeObject(3);
    }
      if (Room.totalPeeps == 0) {
          setLocation(250,250);
          GreenfootImage img = getImage();
          img.setFont(img.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
          setImage(new GreenfootImage("YOU WIN!!" , 75, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK));
          Greenfoot.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using **numbers** for variable names?

Comment: @Bálint no its a group project and we used our names as the classes, so I replaced them with numbers

Comment: Then name it something sensical, it should at least compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a `getWorld().removeObject();` there will be no instances of the classes anymore in the container, and hence trying to access the first element at index 0 will throw that exception. You need to add in size checks.

So you would want to write something like

```
if (getWorld().getObjects(2.class).size() > 0)
{
    Actor 2 = (Actor)getWorld().getObjects(2.class).get(0);
    if(2.getX() == getX() & 2.getY() == getY()) {
        getWorld().removeObject(2);
    }
}
... same for the other two
```

Comment: how would i go about doing that?